# могу ли я расположить два блока в одной ячейке grid

Tags: html, css, grid

блок слева занимает одну строку и одну колонку, могу ли я сделать так, чтобы блоки справа разостились так как на картинке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.cards-grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 280px);
}

.bloksleva {
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
    grid-area: span 1 / span 2 / auto / auto;
}

.about-5 {
    background-color: rgb(143, 87, 131);
    grid-area: span 1 / span 3 / auto / auto;
}
.about-6 {
    background-color: rgb(0, 255, 157);
    grid-area: span 1 / span 3 / auto / auto;
}
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/alexeyabramov/pen/abLBQGy

Comment: @Алексей спасибо